# php ignore errors and continue inserting json data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, insert

Done a lot of reading across multiple sites and unfortunately have not found a solution to this. So any help would be highly appreciated.

I have a php script that reads json data from a URL and then inserts the data into a mysql database. Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error

> "JSON Error : 3 Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded".

What does this error mean and how can I ignore it and/or skip the problematic record and continue inserting the data into mysql?

Below is a view of the php script:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$host = "*****";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Error in  
Connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

$st = mysqli_prepare ($con, 'INSERT INTO PlacesTable (Establishment_Name, 
Establishment_Image, Telephone_Number,BookingNumber,) 

VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');


mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, 'ssss', 

$Name, $Image, $Telephone_Number,$BookingNumber);


$jsondata = file_get_contents("https://websitename.html");
echo $jsondata; 

$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
if ( json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE ) {
echo 'JSON Error : ' . json_last_error() . 
' ' . 
json_last_error_msg();
exit;
print_r($alldata);
}

foreach ($data["Places"] as $row) {

$Name = $row['Name'];
$Image = $row['Image'];
$Telephone_Number = $row['Telephone_Number'];
$BookingNumber = $row['BookingNumber'];

mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
echo mysqli_errno($con) . ": " . mysqli_error($con) . "\n";

}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You can use a try/catch block to skip past errors, and you can also use that to `var_dump()` or log bad data.

Comment: Show the JSON that causes the error maybe?

Comment: You should isolate the problem by echoing each record and then you will find which one is the root cause of error.

Comment: so i added the try/catch function (see below) hopefully I've added it correctly? Still gives the error and stops though, so maybe I've included it incorrectly.

foreach ($data["Establishments"] as $row) {
        try {
        $Name = $row['Name'];
        $Image = $row['Image'];
        $Telephone_Number = $row['Telephone_Number'];
        $BookingNumber = $row['BookingNumber'];
            mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
            echo mysqli_errno($con) . ": " . mysqli_error($con) . "\n";
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {}
        }

Comment: I've also tested the json file to make sure it is valid

Comment: I reckon your encoding is off , do `file_get_contents("http://example.com");
var_dump($http_response_header)` right after and check if it says utf8.

Comment: Thanks paul, so i ran the var_dump and reviewed the output, doesn't make any reference to utf8 encoding. Outputs the below:

array(7) { [0]=> string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" [1]=> string(22) "Cache-Control: private" [2]=> string(23) "Content-Type: text/html" [3]=> string(25) "Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5" [4]=> string(73) "Set-Cookie: *******; secure; path=/" [5]=> string(35) "Date: Mon, 05 Feb 2018 17:34:15 GMT" [6]=> string(17) "Connection: close" }